# Show how old a product is on WooCommerce single product page

Tags: wordpress, date, woocommerce, product

By using the action hook `woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form`, I am trying to check how old the product is by checking if the publish date is older than three months.

If, and only if, the product was published three months ago or more, show a message using a DIV-tag on the product page.

The general idea here is to encourage visitors and registered customers to purchase the product before it goes out of availability, whereof availability means no longer available in the product catalog - as in removing the product for good.

**This is the code I'm working with:**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'encourage_product_purchase' );
function encourage_product_purchase() {
    
    $product_published = 'Availabe since ' . human_time_diff(get_the_time('U'),current_time('timestamp'));
    
    $three_months = '3';

        if ( $product_published >= get_the_time( $three_months ) ) {

            ?>
            <div class="three-month-product">This product has been available for three months and will soon be removed from our catalog. You have 10 days left to purchase.</div>
            <?php

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$product->get_date_created();`

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form() {
    // Get the global product object
    global $product;

    // Is a WC product
    if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
        // Get product date created
        $product_date_created  = $product->get_date_created()->date( 'Y-m-d' );

        // Get now datetime (from Woocommerce datetime object)
        $datetime_now = new WC_DateTime();
        
        // Three months ago from today
        $three_months_ago = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( '-3 months', strtotime( $datetime_now ) ) );
        
        // Compare
        if ( strtotime( $product_date_created ) < strtotime( $three_months_ago ) ) {
            echo '<div class="three-month-product">' . __('This product has been available for three months and will soon be removed from our catalog. You have 10 days left to purchase.', 'woocommerce' ) . '</div>';
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'action_woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 10, 0 );
```

Comment: Why do we need to check is_a product when using a hook that is only available for products?

Comment: There is a difference between `is_product()`, that returns true on a single product page. (Indeed not necessary with this hook) and `is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' )`that checks if the global variable product actually exists. It will work without it, but an extra check never hurts to avoid possible errors

Answer (score 2):

The following function will **add a custom message** based on the product creation date only:

- if the product **creation date is greater than or equal to 3 months**
- if you are on the **product page**

The code has been tested and works.

```
// displays a customized message on the product page based on the product creation date
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'encourage_product_purchase', 10 );
function encourage_product_purchase() {

    // only on the single product page
    if ( ! is_product() ) {
        return;
    }

    // gets the product object
    global $product;
    if ( ! is_object( $product ) ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );
    }

    // get the product creation date in "Y-m-d" format
    $product_date_created  = $product->get_date_created()->format('Y-m-d');
    // gets the date three months ago from today
    $date_three_months_ago = date( "Y-m-d", strtotime( '-3 months' ) );

    // if the product was created 3 months ago or more it displays a message
    if ( $product_date_created <= $date_three_months_ago ) {
        echo '<div class="three-month-product">' . __( 'This product has been available for three months and will soon be removed from our catalog. You have 10 days left to purchase.', 'woocommerce' ) . '</div>';
    }

}
```

*Add it in the functions.php of your active theme.*